# dplyr separate with regex

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following dataframe. It has 1 column of text that I would like to separate into multiple columns using the separate function from dplyr.

```
df <- structure(list(CPT.Codes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("28296 - CORRECTION OF BUNION...., 64445P - N BLOCK INJ, SCIATIC, SNG, 76942P - US GUIDE, NEEDLE PLACEMENT", 
"36821 - AV FUSION DIRECT ANY SITE, 99100P - ANESTHESIA FOR PT OF EXTREME AGE", 
"41899 - DENTAL SURGERY PROCEDURE", "50593 - PERC CRYO ABLATE RENAL TUM, 99100P - ANESTHESIA FOR PT OF EXTREME AGE", 
"64721 - CARPAL TUNNEL SURGERY"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

My desired output is the dataframe below. Each 5-digit number or 5-digit number + letter represents the code and the text following the dash is the code's description. Sometime's the code's description has single-digit numbers and multiple commas, so the regular expression will need to recognize the 5-digit number as a new code.

```
dfDesired <- structure(list(CPTcode1 = c(36821L, 28296L, 41899L, 50593L, 64721L
), CPTdescrip1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("AV FUSION DIRECT ANY SITE", 
"CARPAL TUNNEL SURGERY", "CORRECTION OF BUNION....", "DENTAL SURGERY PROCEDURE", 
"PERC CRYO ABLATE RENAL TUM"), class = "factor"), CPTcode2 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("64445P", "99100P"), class = "factor"), 
    CPTdescrip2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = c("ANESTHESIA FOR PT OF EXTREME AGE", 
    "N BLOCK INJ"), class = "factor"), CPTcode3 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "76942P", class = "factor"), CPTdescrip3 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "US GUIDE NEEDLE PLACEMENT", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I have tried variations of the code below. It is wrong. I am new to regular expressions, and cannot figure this out with existing examples.

```
 CPT %>%
  separate(CPT.Codes, 
           into = c("CPTcode1", "CPTdescrip1", "CTPcode2", "CPTdescrip2", "CPTcode3", "CPTdescrip3"),
           sep = "(?<=[A-Z]) ?(?=[0-9])", remove = F) %>% 
  glimpse
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sep = ",(?=\\s*\\d{5})\\s*|\\s+-\\s+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split with

```
sep = ",(?=\\s*\\d{5})\\s*|\\s+-\\s+"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUT2Ae/1).

**Details**

- `,(?=\s*\d{5})\s*` - a comma `,` that is followed with 0+ whitespaces and then any five digits, and then 0+ whitespaces
- `|`  - or
- `\s+-\s+` - a `-` char enclosed with 1+ whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not as general (won't work if you have more than 3 possible patterns), but maybe more readable, you can use `unglue_unnest()` :

```
library(magrittr)
library(unglue)

patterns <- c(
  "{CPTcode1} - {CPTdescrip1}, {CPTcode2=[^ ]+} - {CPTdescrip2}, {CPTcode3=[^ ]+} - {CPTdescrip3}",
  "{CPTcode1} - {CPTdescrip1}, {CPTcode2=[^ ]+} - {CPTdescrip2}",
  "{CPTcode1} - {CPTdescrip1}")

unglue_unnest(df, CPT.Codes, patterns)
#>   CPTcode1                CPTdescrip1 CPTcode2                      CPTdescrip2 CPTcode3                CPTdescrip3
#> 1    36821  AV FUSION DIRECT ANY SITE   99100P ANESTHESIA FOR PT OF EXTREME AGE     <NA>                       <NA>
#> 2    28296   CORRECTION OF BUNION....   64445P        N BLOCK INJ, SCIATIC, SNG   76942P US GUIDE, NEEDLE PLACEMENT
#> 3    41899   DENTAL SURGERY PROCEDURE     <NA>                             <NA>     <NA>                       <NA>
#> 4    50593 PERC CRYO ABLATE RENAL TUM   99100P ANESTHESIA FOR PT OF EXTREME AGE     <NA>                       <NA>
#> 5    64721      CARPAL TUNNEL SURGERY     <NA>                             <NA>     <NA>                       <NA>
```